# Pylance syntax highlighting randomly stopped working (mac)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

The syntax highlighting feature of Pylance randomly stopped working today (nothing obvious that I was doing that triggered it, just stopped).

This is what it looks like now - before the variables and modules were in different colors, like api_session in example.

[image]

I'm on the latest version of Pylance and VSCode. Tried uninstall / reinstall of both Pylance and VSCode, and computer restart, no joy.

Anyone had this before?

Comment: Pylance doesn't highlight functions if it cant resolve the type of the object. If you hover over the object and it says `type: Any` then there won't be any highlighting of members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` in your settings.

For me, it seems that in an update, it was changed to None.